# .hgignore ignores pattern starting with /

Tags: mercurial, gitignore, hgignore

I'm trying to convert a gitignore.io file to mercurial using `syntax: glob` at the top of the file and renamed it as `.hgignore`. The problem is that patterns starting with `/` like `/vendor/` don't work.

**Does Mercurial ignore file doesn't work with patterns starting with `/`?**

I have searched in the documentation of mercurial but I can't find something specific about starting a glob with `/`, only about how to make rooted patterns with `rootglob`.

For now, I have removed manually all starting patterns with `/` as a workaround.